# Perl: Removing element with special character from an array

Tags: perl

I am able to remove elements from an array when it's a device name or an ip address but when there ie special character in element name below command is not working.

Kindly advice as I have tried 2-3 ways and all are not working ...

For example if key value is network or ip 100.100.100.100 below logic is working fine but when key name is net-switch  or router-net it's not removing.

```
option1 

@array = eval { grep { $_ != $Key } @array1; };

Option2
@array = eval{ grep { $_->[0] ne "$Key" } @array1; }; 


2014/06/29 11:14:56 $VAR1 = [
          '100.2.2.3-0-2',
          '100.4.7.1-0-2',
          '100.2.120.2-0-2',
          '100.1.2.29-3-2',
          'network-0-2',
          'switch-1-1',
          'network-0-2',
          'router45',
           ];
```

Thanks,

Comment: try option three `@array = grep { $_ ne $Key } @array1;`

Comment: Run-able script with actual $key and @array would be helpful. As always use warnings and strict;

Comment: I am getting error Can't use string ("network-xyz") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at

Comment: mpapec @array contains list of router , switch names and network information. and key is ip address ,router name and names with special character I mean with dashes ..

Comment: Please do `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@array;` and provide excerpt of the output so we know exactly the data structure.

Comment: Also want to add if I am printing array records it's showing correctly ..for my $record (@array) {  DEBUG("DEBUG: $record "); }


Output 

network-abc
switch-123
router1
router45
network98
network-89

Comment: @buff dumper's output is as below 2014/06/29 11:14:56 $VAR1 = [
          '100.2.2.3-0-2',
          '100.4.7.1-0-2',
          '100.2.120.2-0-2',
          '100.1.2.29-3-2',
          'network-0-2',
          'switch-1-1',
          'network-0-2',
          'router45',
           ];

Comment: I have updated main question with dumper's output

Comment: My guess is that you got the `strict refs` error because of the option 2, where you do `$_->[0]`, i.e. pretending that `$_` is an array reference while it is a string. Try to remove option 2 and run again my option 3. BTW: What is in $Key?

Comment: Option1 and option2 means I have tried both the options separately ... key is "100.4.7.1-0-2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (
          '100.2.2.3-0-2',
          '100.4.7.1-0-2',
          '100.2.120.2-0-2',
          '100.1.2.29-3-2',
          'network-0-2',
          'switch-1-1',
          'network-0-2',
          'router45',
           );

# my $key = '100.2.2.3-0-2'; # Either of these will work 
my $key = 'network-0-2';

my @keep;
foreach (@array){
    push @keep, $_ unless $_ eq $key;
}

print Dumper \@keep;
```

---

```
100.2.2.3-0-2
100.4.7.1-0-2
100.2.120.2-0-2
100.1.2.29-3-2
switch-1-1
router45
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .If I don't want to print the record,Can I write like foreach (@array){
    unless $_ eq $key;
    push(array1 , $key); 
}

Answer (score 3):

`!=` is numeric `not equal` operator, but since you want to test string inequality use `ne` operator

```
my @array = grep { $_ ne $Key } @array1;
```